# How to edit mode, can create a new record

Tags: apex, visualforce, page-layout, record

My problem,

I would like saving an edit mode don't update a records but create a new record. This is to keep a history of modifications.
I can't find a solution. Should be create a relationship object or a specific button ?
Then it's possible to see two record on one pageLayout ?

I hope you understand me. Thank's

Comment: Are you aware that the platform allows you to nominate up to 20 fields on an object for which changes are tracked - see e.g. [Tracking Field History for Custom Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history_for_custom_objects.htm&language=en_US). This approach has the advantage that there is only one current version of the object, plus a trail of exactly who changed what field including the old and new values. All the normal Salesforce UI then works well without requiring changes.

Comment: I don't know, I'll take a look. Thank you.

Comment: @Keith C Is it possible to display fields from one object on another object?

Comment: You can use a formula field to display a copy of a parent value in a child object and a rollup field to display the min/max/avg/count etc from a child object in a parent object. But if your data model is complicated copies of data between objects require triggers and they take quite a time to learn how to write well and cover all cases.

Comment: Okay, what I want to do like that. But I would like the data of a field of an object is returned in a page layout of another object page. Is possible ? With Master-Detail for example ?